# Store int inside char array in C

Tags: c, int

I am trying to store int value in char array, and access it again to retrieve value later. here is what i tried, but it is not working as i am looking for.

```
char mem[50];
int* size = (int*)&mem[0];

char* isFree = (char*)&mem[4];

char *t = (char *)&mem[4];
```

Now I want to store 1234, and 'f' in the char array according to the order. (within first 5 bytes)

I am not allowed to use other variables, have to use char array.

```
int a = 1234;
int *size = &a;
```

above one is not allowed.

Comment: You need to read the basics of *pointers*. To store a value you have to do `*size = 1234;`

Comment: i am not allowed to use other variables than using array space.  so this won't work. I edited question. so it will be more clear.

int a = 1234;
size = (int *)&a;

Comment: @Haris That also after allocating memory or pointing to another variable.

Comment: actually i am implementing own malloc. so I am trying this for that work.

Comment: @ameyCU, `size` is pointing to the first element of `mem[]` array. Why would he need to allocate memory?

Comment: @Haris No , I meant when you said to do `*size=1234;` .

Comment: @ameyCU, I meant instead of `size = (int *)1234;`, which he had before. Its now edited.

Comment: @dhanush_c You might want to make it more clear what you want to store where (and possibly also *why*); I read "Now I want to store 1234, and 'f' in size and isFree" but I don't understand it.

Comment: @anatolyg sorry, I edited question, my mistake. sorry about that.

Comment: @Haris I edited because question was not much clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried another way and i got a solution. I am posting it as a help for others.

```
char mem[50];
int* size = (int*)&mem[0];
*size = 1234;

char* isFree = (char*)&mem[4];
*isFree = 'f';

char *t = (char *)&mem[4];

printf("%d\n",*(int*)&mem[0]);
printf("%c\n",*(char*)&mem[4]);
```

I assigned a pointer to a pointer. I worked. Thank you all for answering.

Comment: On select systems, `mem[]` maybe not be properly aligned for an `int` array, so  `int* size = (int*)&mem[0];`  is UB.

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the type `unsigned char` to copy the memory or memcpy which does that for you. Aliasing a char array as an int is undefined in C.

store the value:

```
int value = 1234;
memcpy( mem, &value, sizeof(value) );
```

retrieve the value:

```
memcpy( &value, mem, sizeof(value) );
```

(The array `mem` must be large enough to hold the type int.)

Comment: thank you for answering my question. but this won't work. i am not allowed to use other variables than using array space. if not i can do this by using  int a = 1234; size = (int *)&a; that's the issue

Comment: Why not `char`? I see both mentioned in the description of strict aliasing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/99010/509868). Is there some additional rule I am not aware of?

Comment: @anatolyg Signed char could potentially have a value with trap representation if using one's complement or sign+magnitude, if I read the C11 Standard correctly: 6.2.6.2,p2.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sprintf` -

```
int size=1234;
char mem[50];
sprintf(mem,"%d",size);
```

**Note**- This will append null terminator.